# Round x up to next multiple of y

Tags: php

I have two numbers, `$x` and `$y` (both defined by the user on input). I would like to round `$x` to the **next** multiple of `$y`.

For example...

- `$x` is 23
- `$y` is 7
- result is 28 (4*7)

Because $y is variable, it is quite hard to find a single function that will round one with the other. I have seen people do `round($x,-1)` for rounding to the nearest ten, but nothing for rounding to the next multiple.

Does anyone know of a function that will take the two numbers and round **up**?

Comment: Divide x by y. Round result up, then multiply rounded result by y?

Comment: Can you explain by using real numbers and show desired results? Math is not my field

Comment: @Daniel Harrin I don't know PHP, I just know the math. I'm sure someone here can write the answer.

Comment: it's `ceil($x/$y)*$y`

Comment: https://ideone.com/RRWU81

Comment: @Salman A Looks like splash58 and Phiter beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments you can get the desired result by dividing x by y, then rounding up, then multiplying by y.

```
ceil($x/$y)*$y
```